# How to dynamically change the environment name in gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I need to setup the `name` of the `environment` in `gitlab-ci.yml` with the current date and time.

Is this possible? This is what I tried.

```
stages:
  - RUN_TESTS
  # - CLEAN
 
run-test:
  stage: RUN_TESTS
  before_script:
    - echo "Running the tests..."
    - aws configure set aws_access_key_id ${SPOT_RUNNER_ACCESS_KEY} 
    - aws configure set aws_secret_access_key ${SPOT_RUNNER_SECRET_KEY}
    - aws configure set default.region ap-southeast-2
    - $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region ap-southeast-2)   
    - export BUCKET_NAME="effi-allure-reports"   
    - export date=$(date)
  script:
    - echo "test"
  only:
    - develop
  tags:
    - itela-spot-runner
  environment: 
    name: $date
```

But when the pipeline runs, it says

> This job is creating a deployment to .

that means that value has not been set. Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a dynamic environment name use a [Predefined CI variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html),

```
stages: 
  - deploy

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "This is a test Deploy"
  environment:
    name: $CI_JOB_STARTED_AT
```

depending on the datetime you want to register the name of the environment you got three options:

1. `CI_JOB_STARTED_AT`. "The UTC datetime when a job started".
2. `CI_PIPELINE_CREATED_AT`. "The UTC datetime when the pipeline was created".
3. `CI_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP`. "The timestamp of the commit."

worth mentioning they are in ISO8601 format. Complete [reference](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/#create-a-dynamic-environment) for more details.

Comment: I can't use any of these as I have self hosted gitlab and it is running `12.4.2` :(

Comment: Doesn't work for $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME. The environment tag can not be set dynamically, and gitlab doesn't seem to plan to fix it. It's been an issue for years.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the documentation, you can not expand a variable from the script section [1]: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#environment

One possible solution is to use the predefined CI variables `CI_JOB_STARTED_AT` or `CI_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP` [2]: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html

Answer (score 0):

You can have a prepare stage before deploy to parse your env variables

```
prepare_release:
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  stage: prepare   
  rules:
  - if: '($CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event") && ($CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "master")'
    when: on_success
  script:
    - echo "DATE=`date -u +%d_%b_%Y`" >> variables.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: variables.env
```

Through which you can access the date in next job using needs

```
needs:
  - job: prepare_release
    artifacts: true
script:
  - echo "Running release at $DATE"
environment: 
  name: $DATE
```

If you can't afford an additional job then you've to live with predefined date env variables

Comment: this doesn't seem to work. the dotenv variable is ignored

Comment: The question asks about `environment.name` (**environment name**), and yet this answer has nothing to do with it. Perhaps you're confusing environment name with environment variables @Prashanna

Comment: @BenButterworth Actually, this is a good workaround to deal with the "GitLab environment"'s environment variables as they must be set before the job starts. what @Prashanna  has done is setting variables in `prepare` step and they load on the next step. any other variable, such as name, URL, etc., can be set this way.

Comment: @Peyman The thing, though, is that the workaround… doesn't work. Many job properties like `environment`, `image` etc. do not support variables from dotenv artifacts, as @AbdallahDeeb says.

Comment: This will not work, and it does not answer the question. $DATE env must be known when the pipeline is created; any changes to $DATE in any other jobs will not impact the default value used during pipeline creation.

to use this kind of env in a dynamic way, we need to create a dynamic pipeline in GitLab